# To save file using URLDownloadToFile in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I have a requirement to login to site using vb .net and dynamically get the file from URL and save it to hard disk. I was wondering if I can use URLDownloadToFile to save my file to disk as this is one of the option I found after googling a little. But using this function in my code gives me error as follows 'URLDownloadToFile' is not declared.It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
Am I missing any references here?

```
    Imports SHDocVw
Imports mshtml
Imports System.Net

 Module Module1
 Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
 Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
 Sub Main()
 MyGmail()
 End Sub
Sub MyGmail()

Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
MyURL = "https://example.com/"
 MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.Navigate(MyURL)
MyBrowser.Visible = True
 Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.ReadyState = tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE
HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.Document
HTMLDoc.all.txtUserID.Value = "xyz@example.com" 'Enter your email id here
HTMLDoc.all.txtPassword.Value = "test123" 'Enter your password here

For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.click() : Exit For
Next

 'Navigate to reports folder
 Dim newReportURL As String
 newReportURL = "https://some_static_url_to_navigate"
MyBrowser.Navigate(newReportURL)
Dim i As Integer
 Dim reportURL As String
 reportURL = ""
i = 0
  For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
If DirectCast(MyHTML_Element, mshtml.IHTMLAnchorElement).innerText = "Export" And i = 1 Then

    reportURL = DirectCast(MyHTML_Element, mshtml.IHTMLAnchorElement).href
   End If

  If DirectCast(MyHTML_Element, mshtml.IHTMLAnchorElement).innerText = "Export" Then
    i = i + 1
End If


 Next

  MyBrowser.Navigate(reportURL)

For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then
    MyHTML_Element.click() : Exit For
End If

Next


Dim xlsReportURL As String
xlsReportURL = DirectCast(MyBrowser.Document, mshtml.IHTMLDocument).url

'Not working it gets the page HTML
MyBrowser.ExecWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_SAVEAS,      OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, savePath, vbNull)

Err_Clear:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Err.Clear()
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Please post your code so it can be reviewed

Comment: I have added the code, please review

Comment: You have this tagged as VB.NET and VBA.  It can't be both, as they both have different libraries for HTTP access.  Which one is it?  It looks like VBA

Comment: I am not much familiar with VBA. I found this code here http://www.familycomputerclub.com/how-to-login-automatically-into-website-using-excel-vba.html and i built it using vb.net

Comment: I have moved the code to VBA still it gives issue "sub or function not defined"

Comment: the code in the example you linked is VBA