# Dynamically login to site using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I have a requirement for web scraping where I have to login to site dynamically perform some events on control on page and finally download a file from particular URL.
I am able to login and get file URL using vb, I was wondering if same can be achieved using jquery?.Link for my .net code here [To save file using URLDownloadToFile in Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421708/to-save-file-using-urldownloadtofile-in-visual-basic)

Comment: A login request is usually a `POST` request with some `username` and `password` parameter. Have you looked into that?

Comment: could please you share any link how to do this.

Comment: Well there's quite a few steps involved and it's hard to go into detail without knowing anything about the site you're interested in. I suggest looking into http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ with the goal of sending a `POST` request to the site.